# Is it possible to use <c:if> inside <a4j:repeat>

Tags: jsf, jstl, repeat, ajax4jsf

Is it possible to use `<c:if>` inside `<a4j:repeat>`?

I need to render a `<br />` each 4 elements. I tried the following approach:

```
<a4j:repeat value="#{MBean.sucursal.events}" var="item" rowKeyVar="idx" >   
   <h:outputText value="#{item.eventDescription}" id="item1" />
   <c: if test=#{idx % 4 == 0}>
       <br />
   </c:if>
</a4j:repeat>
```

However, it does not render the `<br />` elements at all.

How can I achieve the requirement anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: I'll ignore the careless formulation of the code which causes that it wouldn't compile/run properly at all. There's a space in `<c :if>` and the quotes are missing from the `<c:if test>` attribute. In future questions please pay a bit more attention to the properness of the code snippets you post, otherwise you'll only get invalid answers due to those red herrings.

---

Coming back to your concrete problem, this construct will indeed fail. The `<c:if>` runs during view build time (when the JSF component tree is about to be populated based on Facelets/JSP files), while the `<a4j:repeat>` runs during view render time (when the HTML code is about to be generated based on the JSF component tree). So, at the moment the `<c:if>` runs, `#{idx}` does not exist in the scope at all and always evaluates to `null`.

There are basically 2 solutions:

1. Use `<c:forEach>` instead of `<a4j:repeat>` to iterate over the items. It runs during view build time, so it'll run "in sync" with `<c:if>`.

   ```html
   <c:forEach items="#{MBean.sucursal.events}" var="item" varStatus="loop">   
      <h:outputText value="#{item.eventDescription}" id="item#{loop.index}" />
      <c:if test="#{loop.index % 4 == 0}">
          <br />
      </c:if>
   </c:forEach>
   ```

   *(note that I changed the `<h:outputText id>` as well, otherwise you end up with duplicate component ID errors or malformed HTML; feel free to omit the `id` attribute altogether, JSF will autogenerate proper one)*
2. Use JSF component's `rendered` attribute instead of `<c:if>` to conditionally render HTML. It runs during view render time, so it'll run "in sync" with `<a4j:repeat>`.

   ```html
   <a4j:repeat value="#{MBean.sucursal.events}" var="item" rowKeyVar="idx">   
      <h:outputText value="#{item.eventDescription}" id="item1" />
      <h:panelGroup rendered="#{idx % 4 == 0}">
          <br />
      </h:panelGroup>
   </a4j:repeat>
   ```

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: excelent answer! Thanks a lot!!